# wordpress subdomain lead to main domain

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, subdomain

Basically I want to add a user somewhere in the url so I can get it later and tried the subdomain approach:

```
mike.domain.com  -load- domain.com
nik1233.domain.com/about -load- domain.com/about etc
```

Note that I wish for the url to remain as is (so i can take the name via javascript) and that wordpress already seems to strip www and add https without me seeing anything in the root's htaccess file.

Thus far the only thing I managed is setting wildcard subdomain in cpanel and entering in htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

which worked but shows me a unverified certificate error.

Nearly 5 days later still not figured it out, not even if I should abandon the user.domain.com and go maybe for domain.com/user?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code in root htaccess.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(^.*)\.xyz.com
RewriteRule (.*)  index.php?username=%1&$1  [L,QSA]
```

http://hello.xyz.com/abc/?var=12

```
Array
(
    [username] => abc
    [index_php] => 
    [abc/] => 
    [var] => 12
)
```

Wildcard subdomain is necessary to activate the DNS. you will get the username in query string which you can use inside your code.

Comment: th for quick reply. I have left only your code on the root .htaccess (of course changed the RewriteCond  to match my domain). When you enter mike.example.com it will do a 301 'permanently moved' to https://example.com (changing also the url), when u try https://mike.example.com will display a 'unverified certificate warning' which if u click proceed will again do a 301 redirect to https://example.com. If unable to get wildcard SSL support, would it be possible to add the subdomains like example.com/mike? If ofc they do not confict with the actual pages.

Comment: as per your requirement, it's necessary to have a WildCard SSL so that you can verify any subdomain. example.com/mike will also work but that will not work as a subdomain and also you would need to modify the htaccess code as well.

Comment: well only requirement is to somehow get a variable into the url. if example.com/mike which does not issue a security warning and can be done without meddling with the other pages (/about, /idea etc) it would be acceptable solution (any ideas about the htaccess code for this?). As an alternative I am trying now to save the subdomain in a session b4 wordpress redirects me to example.com and use php to retrieve it but that seems quite a roundabout solution

Comment: Got it. Do you want to keep the username always in the URL or we can store the username in session after the first hit?

Comment: no problem if it vanishes from the url after stored. Btw tried to do it with sessions (store it in session when calling http and then retireving it after redirecting to https) but not seem to work -getting different PHPSESSID all the time and not just from http to https. I mean even http://mike.example.com and http://mike2.example.com will give me different PHPSESSID in the response headers (though https://example.com/idea, https://example.com/about etc keeps same PHPSESSID -maybe problem with change of subdomain/ protocol?)